# E-goi what is the function name that makes the user 's email validation that will receive the newsletters

Tags: php, wordpress, function

im using e-goi and i whant to know if possibel what is the function name that makes the user 's email validation that will receive the newsletters.

tks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe this?
http://www.e-goi.com/en/recursos/api/testemailaddress/

Can you explain what are you trying to do?

Comment: yeah is that i need, im making a plugin to wordpress and i want a option that the user can say with a checkbox if he want to receive the confirmation email or can say he accept , don't need to send the email , something like that :)  tks for the Anwser

Comment: i read wrong and that's not what i want, usually we receive e-mail to confirm that we agree with something , I want the person can say that does not need to receive this email and accepting , that through the one check box, did you understand me ?